# Resize imagen from canvas.toDataURL

Tags: canvas

I have a problem.. I want to load an image from a canvas. It works fine. the problem is whe I try to define a percent width to the final image. The image doen't respect the percent defined.

This is the code:

1) The canvas definition

```
<div style="display:block;">
    <canvas id="id_canvas_nz" width="1196px" height="808px"></canvas>
</div>
```

2) The image where I want to put the final image generated in the canvas

```
<div style="width:75%">
    <img id="id_image_def_nz" width="100%" src="" style="float:left" />
</div>
```

3) Load one image in the canvas + Some transformations + Put the canvas result in the image with id "id_image_def_nz"

```
<script>

    var canvas_nz = document.getElementById("id_canvas_nz");
    var ctx_nz = canvas_nz.getContext("2d");

    // Define image

    var img_nz = new Image();

    img_nz.src = "./image.png";


    // When image is load:

    img_nz.onload = function()
    {

        // Draw the image in the canvas

        ctx_nz.drawImage(img_nz, 0, 0);


        // Transformations in the image:

        ...
        ...

        // Put the canvas into the redimensionated image

        var img2_nz = document.getElementById("id_image_def_nz");
        img2_nz.src = canvas_nz.toDataURL("image/png");

    }

</script>
```

Ok, it puts the content of the canvas in my image. But not redimensionated at 100% of the DIV. Put this at normal size, without resizing the image.

How can I do this??

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Sorry.. the answer is soooo easy.. The problem was the area of the canvas. It was not enough to house the image. So, in the canvas, the image was partially loaded. Therefore, in the final result, I thought that the image didn't resize. When, really, the problem was in the canvas was not loaded all the image..

Sorry, and thank you! :)